# t-sql TVF function slow when using localvariables in "CASE statement"

Tags: performance, t-sql, case

I have sql like below inside a Multi-Step Table valued function..I have shortened the query a bit to make it easy to understand.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ph] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @pAsOfDate date,
    @pAccountId nvarchar(15)
)
RETURNS @HH TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    AsOfDate date,
    AccountId nvarchar(15), 
    LongName varchar(100),
    ShortName varchar(100)
)
AS

BEGIN

declare @longOrShortIndicator int
select @longOrShortIndicator = COUNT(distinct LongOrShortIndicator) from table1 a


select a.*,
 case 
    when a.SecType='CASH' and @longOrShortIndicator > 1 then 'C'
    else a.LongOrShortIndicator
 end as LongOrShortIndicator
from Table1 a

END
```

The expression `when a.SecType='CASH' and @longOrShortIndicator > 1 then 'C'` is the bottleneck.

if i remove the `@longOrShortIndicator > 1` the query runs fast

If i run the query outside of the function it returns fast...

Why is the local variable slowing down the entire query? Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Please show how are you using this function, perhaps in JOIN/WHERE? clause

Comment: select * from [fn_PortfolioHoldings]('01-31-2012','A_470_P')

Comment: It is so strange that using the local variable in the case is slowing down the query considerably.

Answer (score 1):

The listing does not show what you want to do with @HH, your return table, but in @longOrShortIndicator you are obviously counting rows in table1. If you're doing it many times, e.g. for all rows of your return table, then it is slow indeed, it would be slow even on the death star.

Comment: +1:  More specifically, it's fast when you comment out the variable because the optimizer is eliminating the SELECT COUNT step to populate the unused variable.  Try moving the select count bit outside the function and send the count in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here: maybe you could try moving the @LongOrShortIndicator variable out of the query and into an IF statement:

```
declare @longOrShortIndicator int
select @longOrShortIndicator = COUNT(distinct LongOrShortIndicator) from table1 a

IF @longOrShortIndicator > 1 BEGIN
    select a.*,
        CASE when a.SecType='CASH' then 'C'
        else a.LongOrShortIndicator
        end as LongOrShortIndicator
    from Table1 a
END ELSE BEGIN
    select a.*, a.LongOrShortIndicator
    from Table1 a
END
```